# Provide both a synchronous and asynchronous API with promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I'm creating a library where the consumer of the library should be able to go through different steps in the library, and the consumer should be able to decide when the library to go to the next step. To achieve that, I let the consumer pass promises to the library, which the consumer then can resolve when it's time to go to the next step. A dummy example would be this:

```js
// A library function.
export async function processName(getNamePromise){
    
    const name = await getNamePromise
    
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`)
    
}
```

Now the consumer can decide when the library should go to the next step in the library by resolving the promise. A dummy example:

```
import {processName} from './the-lib.js'

const getNamePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    document.getElementById(`inputName`).addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
       // This JS code does probably not work as it is, but you get the idea.
       if(event.keyCode == "enter"){
           resolve(event.target.value)
       }
    })
})

processName(getNamePromise)
```

This works great! But, sometimes I want to use the library synchronously. I was hoping that passing an already resolved promise to the library would make it run synchronously, but each `await` in the library seems to put the next step at the end of the event queue, so `processName()` will in fact run asynchronously anyway:

```
import {processName} from './the-lib.js'

const getNamePromise = Promise.resolve(`Peter`)

processName(getNamePromise)
console.log(`Done processing!`)
```

With the code above, `Done processing` is logged before `Hello Peter!`. I need it to be the other way around.

I really, really want to avoid using `await` when calling `processName()` with a resolved promise, because I need to do this in a frontend framework that automatically re-runs computations as soon as a reactive variable changes, and to speed things up, I also need to use caching of method calls. Being able to use the library in a synchronous way here would be so much easier. And it all would have worked great if `await`ing a resolved promise wouldn't have resulted in a new job in the event queue... -.-

In the library, a workaround that would work is to check if the promise has been resolved or not, and only use `await` if it hasn't been resolved, something like this:

```js
// A library function.
export async function processName(getNamePromise){
    
    const name = getNamePromise.isResolved() ? getNamePromise.getResolvedValue() : await getNamePromise
    
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`)
    
}
```

But `Promise.isResolved()` and `Promise.getResolvedValue()` don't exist, and it is a messy solution anyway.

My current workaround is to not wrap the name in a promise when the code should run synchronously, and only use `await` in the lib when it receives a promise:

```js
// A library function.
export async function processName(getNamePromise){
    
    const name = typeof getNamePromise == "string" ? getNamePromise : await getNamePromise
    
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`)
    
}
```

```
import {processName} from './the-lib.js'

const name = `Peter`

processName(name)
console.log(`Done processing!`)
```

Still quite messy, but this is how I do it for now. Does anyone know if a better solution exists to provide a library where the consumer can pass promises to the library (to tell the library when to go to the next "step"), but also special cases where the library should run synchronously?

And does anyone know why `await`ing a resolved promise pushes a new job to the event queue? Is it not more logical and faster to simply finish the current job when `await`ing a promise that is already resolved?

Comment: Node.js module `fs` is doing it by providing Promise API and Synchronous API. For example `readFile()` and `readFileSync()` - the first one is a Promise, the second one returns synchronously. Don't know if that's acceptable for you but I'm just throwing an idea

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SebastianKaczmarek. It sure is a valid alternative. Intuitively it doesn't feel like a perfect solution having to maintain two different APIs (more work, and have a bug in one but no the other, making them function different, etc.), but perhaps that's the best solution, so good that you brought it up!